# Nexus 5 SDCARD files are not writable from PC USB

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, stock-android, file-transfer

I was trying to update my TWRP thought Google play store TWRP app. It did apply some sdcard pactch, which I later removed it.

But after that when ever I try to access files of my nexus 5 storage I cant write or delete stuff.

Below image you can see my phone is getting detected, But I cant copy paste music in my phone.

[image]

Also, if I try to access my sdcard from Root file manager it comes empty,

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

I have even tried uninstalling MTP drivers and installed again. But it seems some File permission issue on my sdcard itself !!

Comment: Just an updated, I have updated my TWRP to 2.8.3.0 thru ADB, I used the fix permission inside it. But still not resolved.

Comment: My first guess from your screenshots was: could it be you're not using MTP, but UMS (USB mass storage) – as when accessed from the PC, the card seems empty on the device? That wouldn't explain the "write protection", but might be part of the issue.

Comment: im updating my phone to new 5.0.1 now, lets see after

Comment: even in 5.0.1 same issue. not sure wht the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sdcard permission issue created by TWRP Manager app from google play store.

I had to flashed 5.0 and then 5.0.1 again from fastboot. everything works fine now.